# Reinstall Mac OS without touching Windows partition

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac

I have a macbook pro with version 10.8.5. But now I have some problems and I cannot upgrade any SW. Any updates I do fail, including upgrade to Mavericks, LibreOffice, Adobe Flush player etc.
So I figured I need to do a fresh OS X Mavericks installation.
I do not have a Mac external drive that I can use with TimeMachine for backup.
I have 2 partitions on my HD - one for Windows 7. This is an OEM version so I cannot re-install it.

Can I do a fresh OS installation, that will effect only my Mac partition and leave the windows untouched?
What about Itunes files -how can I backup so that I will not loose all my pictures. videos, music etc. on my iPad when I synchronize it after the new installation?

Thanks,
Danny

Comment: Reinstalling OS X is almost never necessary. Use Disk Utility to run both kinds of disk first aid scans: "Repair Disk Permissions" and "Repair Disk" for your Mac partition. Also, select the drive itself and do a "Repair Disk" of that to make sure the GPT and PMBR are both set up correctly. Use the Console utility to see what log messages you get when you try to update apps. Also look at the installer logs.